# Modify string repr of functions for use in dict keys

Tags: python, function

Is it possible and recommended to modify string representation of python function and parameters for interactive use?

Use case is to use functions as dict keys since functions are hashable. For example:

```
def addn(n):
    return lambda x: x+n
```

can then define keys:

```
{addn(1): 'foo', addn(2): 'bar'}
```

and then use the keys computationally:

```
{k(10):v for k,v in {addn(1): 'foo', addn(2): 'bar'}.items()}

>> {11: 'foo', 12: 'bar'}
```

In interactive notebooks, would be desirable to see 'addn(1)' etc as string rather than:

```
{<function __main__.addn.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>: 'some-json',
 <function __main__.addn.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>: 'more-json'}
```

**edit: changed the values to indicate that typical values of interest are usually complex data - previously i had 'foo' and 'bar'. I likely  confused some, the values are independent of the keys - this is not an antipattern, it's a common pattern in data science with complex keys - generalization of frozendict keys.

Could this be done w decorator, without defining a derivative function class and without introducing undesirable consequence?

Note it's critical to display the parameters as well as function name as these are data of interest.

Comment: If this matters you should probably have a class implementing `__repr__` and `__call__` (plus `__hash__` and `__eq__` for the dict usage).

Comment: this definitely seems like some kind of antipattern ...

Comment: And most likely XY problem, in my opinion. _display the parameters as well as function name as these are data of interest_

Comment: @JoranBeasley, this is definitely a workaround to py dict being based on hash table rather than more flexible structure like tries - eg Mathematica - which allow non-hashable keys - which is a usable pattern in data science.

Comment: @buran, i edited the q slightly, hopefully it's a little more clear. The problem is hashable keys limitation of dict. You'll have to believe me that it's a common pattern in data science to have complex keys, more general than frozendict. The idea is to use function as a generic wrapper but also display parameter, for example if the key is `frozendict.frozendict({'a': 1})`, `{'a':1}` is the parameter and it is displayed. Want the same behavior with function wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you need to use a class to wrap this

note im just answering the question .... I dont think this is a very good idea

import inspect

```
class BaseX:
    NO_RESULT = object()
    def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.result is not BaseX.NO_RESULT and callable(self.result):
            return self.result(*args,**kwargs)
        return BaseX(self.fn,args,kwargs)
    def __init__(self,fn,args=None,kwargs=None):
        self.called_with = None
        self.result = BaseX.NO_RESULT
        if args is not None and kwargs is not None:
            self.result = fn(*args,**kwargs)
            msg = "("
            if args:
                msg += ", ".join(map(str,args))
            if kwargs:
                msg += ", " + ", ".join(f"{k}={v!r}" for k,v in kwargs.items())
            msg += f")"
            self.called_with = msg

        self.fn = fn
        self.args = inspect.signature(fn)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fn.__name__ + (self.called_with if self.called_with else str(self.args))
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(str(self))

@BaseX
def addn(n):
    return lambda x: x+n

a1 = {addn(1): 'foo', addn(2): 'bar'}
print("A1:",a1)
a2 = {k(10):v for k,v in {addn(1): 'foo', addn(2): 'bar'}.items()}
print(a2)
```

Comment: hey Joran, this is a good approach but it doesn't have intended behavior. I expected it to behave like a generalized frozendict, for example, group by frozendict on this list `[{'a':1},{'a':1},{'b':2},{'c':1}]` results in 3 keys (each a frozendict). Conversely, grouping it by a `@BaseX` wrapped function results in 4 keys and so does the non-decorated version. It appears evaluation of the same function with the same argument `{'a':1}` results in different hashes?

Comment: can you provide the exact case where you don't get the expected output... I was basing my solution on your provided inputs :)

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure I understand the purpose and think this is XY problem, but in this example case (still not 100% what you ask):

```
from functools import partial

def addn(n):
    return lambda x: x+n

spam = {partial(addn, 1):'foo', partial(addn, 2):'bar'}
print(spam)
print({k()(10):v for k, v in spam.items()})
```

output

```
{functools.partial(<function addn at 0x7f34703b01e0>, 1): 'foo', functools.partial(<function addn at 0x7f34703b01e0>, 2): 'bar'}
{11: 'foo', 12: 'bar'}
```

or even better

```
from functools import partial

def addn(n, x):
    return x+n

spam = {partial(addn, 1):'foo', partial(addn, 2):'bar'}
print(spam)
print({k(10):v for k, v in spam.items()})
```

EDIT, thinking further, another way (I complicated it with 2 params)

```
def addn(n, m):
    return lambda x: (x+n)*m

spam = {(addn(1, 2), 1, 2):'foo', (addn(2, 2), 2, 2):'bar'}
print(spam)
print({func(10):v for (func, *_), v in spam.items()})
```

output

```
{(<function addn.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f644e52a268>, 1, 2): 'foo', (<function addn.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f644ce44488>, 2, 2): 'bar'}
{22: 'foo', 24: 'bar'}
```

not very nice, quick and dirty, but still the function and params are clear. Of course you can always define own class instead as suggested by jonrsharpe